# Heroku application errror on newly created application

Tags: heroku, cloud

I've just set up my heroku application and i get this error on my newly created application.[image]

At first i thought heroku takes some time to make the app live, but its been days. Is there any thing i need to do after creating the app.

Comment: can you show us the heroku logs?

Comment: You should do `heroku logs -t --app <your app name>`. Did you deploy the application to Heroku yet?

Comment: But what you do after you create the application is dependent on what language your app is in too.